# How to display Unverified Emails in Array

Tags: arrays

I have following two arrays.

**First Array**

```
Array ( [0] => rogers@gmail.com [1] => peter@gmail.com [2] => john@gmail.com )
```

**Second Array**

```
Array ( [0] => Verified [1] => Unverified [2] => Unverified )
```

In the database they are stored as

```
{"user_email":["rogers@gmail.com","peter@gmail.com","john@gmail.com"],"status":["Verified","Unverified","Unverified"}
```

I want to display all the emails that are **"Unverified"**. How to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to suggest that you store the data in a different format. The way that it is stored now, you must assume that position 0 in the First Array corresponds exactly to position 0 in the Second Array. The way it is now also enforces the arrays to be of equal size to build any sort of algorithm around them to relate the values of Verified/Unverified to the different emails. I would suggest the following:

```
{"email_and_status":[ 
    ["rogers@gmail.com", "Verified"], 
    ["peter@gmail.com", "Unverified"], 
    ["john@gmail.com", "Unverified"]
] }
```

Which results in the single array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => "rogers@gmail.com" [1] => "Verified" ) [1] => Array ( ...
```

And you can just iterate through this array, checking if the second entry is "Unverified" and then saving the first entry in some array for displaying purposes.

As for an answer to your question, I will write the algorithm in some generic pseudocode and then explain it.

```
return_array = [];

for(i = 0; i < length(first_array); i++) {
    if(second_array[i] == "Unverified") {
        return_array.append(first_array[i]);
    }
}
```

The first assumption that must be made here is that the length of the First Array is the same as the length of the Second Array. The code iterates through each array and if the i'th entry in the Second Array is "Unverified", then add the i'th entry of the First Array to the `return_array`. Once the loop is finished, `return_array` should hold the values "peter@gmail.com" and "john@gmail.com", if I'm interpreting your data structure correctly. Alternatively, if you do not actually want to save these values in a new array, you can simply replace `return_array.append(first_array[i]);` with `print(first_array[i]);` which will display the emails as you iterate through the arrays.

NOTE: replace `.append`, `print`, `length`, etc... with whatever is specific to your language.

Comment: Actually I am collecting email and status from an Add / Remove dynamic form input fields. I use JSON_ENCODE to insert in database. Hence I get the above mention format of array. Plz tell me how to convert my array in to ur array format. Thanks

Comment: You most likely need to adhere to the array format before you JSON_ENCODE. Can you post the code that is processing the data before encoding it to JSON format?

Comment: I am obtaining values from Dynamic Add/Remove Fields `$member_details->user_email = array_unique( array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['user_email'] ) );
$member_details->status = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['status'] );

$member_details_encode = wp_json_encode( $member_details );`

Comment: This should help out: `$member_details->user_email = array_unique( array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['user_email'] ) );
$member_details->status = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['status'] );

$member_details->email_and_status = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($member_details->user_email); $i++) {
    $member_details->email_and_status[] = [$member_details->user_email[$i], $member_details->status[$i]];
}

$member_details_encode = wp_json_encode( $member_details );`

Comment: You can add this before the wp_json_encode as well if you would like. It should just get rid of the user_email and status indices in the resulting JSON array, which you may or may not need now: `unset($member_details->user_email);
unset($member_details->status);`

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer

```
for ( $i = 1; $i < count( $member_details->user_email ); $i++ ) {
    $user_status = $member_details->status[ $i ];

    if ( $user_status === 'Unverified' ) {

        echo $member_details->user_email[ $i ];

    }

}
```